# Making a three phase voltage source to drive a gyroscope

Tags: power-supply, inverter, three-phase

I'm trying to drive a gyroscope that needs a 3 phase 400Hz 32v 1A power supply. How can I provide that supply? It's one part of my university project and I'm a beginner in this field. I'd like to find the best way  to provide a suitable supply.
thanks

Comment: Need more info. What source are you trying to work from? How much power are we talking about?

Comment: Are you asking for help in designing your own power supply or in finding one that you can purchase? What exactly do you mean by "cost is important"?

Comment: i editted my question.as i mentioned i'm begineer in this field.unfortunately i don't know more than i menthioned to clarify my Question. i'd be glad to see your helpful answers.

Comment: The Sperry gyrocompass were driven by a 28v DC dynamotor that output 400 cps 3 phase. They can still be found online or militery surplus. That would be the cheapest, fast setup. A gyrocompass can give you your heading, a GPS can provide "Course Over Ground" which saves calculating drift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Johnson counter with a ring of nine outputs ( or greater multiples of 3). Use resistors from each output weighted so that an approximation to a sinewave is created. You can use another set of resistors to create another sinewave at 120 degrees  and ditto for 240 degrees. Now you have a rough approximation to three sinewaves set at the right phase angle for 3 phase. And you can control the output frequency by varying the clock into the Johnson counter.

Alternatively buy and program a DDS chip from analog devices. It does the same effectively.

Comment: could a DDS chip provide 36V ac?

Comment: @user38013 you'd need an op-amp to get 32Vp-p - any higher and most op-amps are running out of power supply capabilities but there are op-amps that can be powered from up to 100V and beyond. I think Linear technology do one.

Comment: thanks...that was very helpful.how can i provide current needed for motor?i dont think op amps could do that.

Comment: They'll easily do 1mA (as per your question) but there op-amps that can do several amps. Try linear technology.

Comment: i changed my question after reading your advices.please help me solving my new Q.

Comment: I'd advise is not to change the content of a question once an answer has been accepted because it might invalidate the answer - I can roll-back to the original question and maybe you should ask a new question - people don't like to see answers that don't seem to fit the question and it's not correct for the EE site - folk like clear answers to clear questions. If you wanted to could add information to the question but also, you are unlikely to get answers to this. Please consider posting a new question and putting this question back to how it was.

Comment: can i give 15% of inverter's input voltage from it's output?(in my inverter the range of output voltage is 40%-110% of input voltage).is there any way to have voltage less than this range in the output? thanks –

Comment: It might be best if you post a new question and put a circuit with it.

Comment: i faced with another problem.my output voltage dosen't change during changing frequency and output voltage on keypad.what is my fault?

Comment: @Eram I don't know. I don't have a circuit diagram - maybe post a new question?

Comment: ihave3-phase power as my inverter's input and a LS-ig5a inverter that is not connected to my motor.i set the inverter's frequency,voltage and other parameters menthioned in it's user manual to reach my ideal Voltage & Frequency.in this way i just have fixed voltage about 260v in it's output(240vac input)that isn't reasonable.i don't know why? e.g. when i set 50hz and my base freqency is 400hz i shuld have about 50v in output but voltmeter shows me 250v!! in the other way in the inverter there is a  paramete(VOL) that displays output voltage.this parameter shows me correct value!!

Comment: @Eram I don't this relates to your question and I don't think anyone on EE will regard this as on-topic for this site. Sorry mate, I can't help you debug a device that I have no knowledge of.